# Auto-complete suggestion within a simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an application where i try to suggest "Similar topics" in rails, as the user put the title of his/her new story.
I have 2 problems:
The controller with the custom action does not work at all. it seems that the server simply retrieves the view. Without running any of the code in the action
To go around the issue of the controller, i created a `service.rb` with a function to retrieve the records based on the `params[:title]`, but from here I do NOT know how to make small popup window with suggestions (and weblinks) as the user write the title of the topic.
I have done so far :

**View**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<%= simple_form_for @message do |f| %>
  <div style="font-size: xx-small; font-style: italic; color: #44B5EB">
  <%= f.input :title, label: "#{t :Title}", placeholder: "#{t :Search}", id: "title" , data: {behavior: "autocomplete_message"}%>
  <%= f.cktext_area :description, label: "#{t :Message_body}", :input_html => {:rows => 25} %>
  <br> <br>
  <%= f.submit "#{t :Create_story}", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>


<script>
    $("#title").addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
        $input = $("[data-behavior = 'autocomplete_message']");
        var options = {
            getValue: "name",
            url: function (phrase) {
                return "messages/search.json?title=" + phrase;
            },
            categories: [
                {
                    listLocation: "qandas",
                    header: "<p class='Search_drop_separate'>Q&A </p>",
                }
            ],
            list: {
                onChooseEvent: function(){
                    var url = $input.getSelectedItemData().url;
                    $input.val("");
                    Turbolinks.visit(url)
                }
            }
        };
        $input.easyAutocomplete(options)
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
class StorytController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  before_action :find_message, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :html, :js  
...

def search

  #@qandasquestions = Qandasquestion.ransack(question_or_answer_cont: params[:q]).result(distinct: true)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
      @qandasquestions = @qandasquestions
      redirect_to stories_search_path
    }
    format.json {
      @qandasquestions = @qandasquestions.limit(5)
    }
  end
end

def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end

private
def force_json
  request.format = :json
end
end

Search.jason.builder
json.qandas do
  json.array!(@qandasquestions) do |qandasquestion|
    json.name "#{qandasquestion.question}"
    json.url qanda_path(qandasquestion.qanda_id)
  end
end
```

routes:

```
  get 'stories/search'
```

What I am looking to build is actually very similar to what we have on Stackoverflow on the principle.
Anybody did something similar and can help me please?

Comment: This is wrong `$("#title").addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {`. Use `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {`. And you have `respond_to :html, :js` but your want to respond to html and JSON not js.

Comment: Hi @arieljuod, Got you on what is wrong. I guess if I am asking here it is because things are wrong and I am looking for a solution. Would you mind suggesting the right way to do it please?

Comment: I already suggested a change: use `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {`) and `respond_to :html, :json`

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to sidetrack you but if you have a couple minutes to check this out, have you seen select2? It works nice with Rails and there's also a gem to make it work nice with simple_form

https://github.com/lndl/select2_simple_form

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Feel free to post comments to the original post, but please reserve answers to your proposed code solution. Thanks!